# Detect browser close and logout user in .Net Core 5

Tags: database, asp.net-core, browser, user-controls, logout

I am working on an application in `Asp.Net Core 5`. In this application, we need to manage users.
If a user does login in the application and closes the browser, he/she will be automatically logged out from the application.

How can I catch the browser close event and logout the user.
NB: User logout time should be written in database.

Comment: Hi @Mehedi Hasan Kajol, which way of login do you use? If you use cookie authentication to login the user, it contains property named `IsPersistent`, you can set it to false to achieve your requirement. But for write the logout time to database, as far as I known, it seems to be impossible?

Comment: Thank you @Rena. I actually do `isPersistent` to false, but just want to know about browser close event. There are lots of jQuery code on the internet but they seem not to work. But I understand now by reading last line of your comment.